# Running Django server on localhost

Tags: django, server, localhost

I would like to run a Django server locally using a local IP.

I have `localhost` mapped here:

```
$ head -n 1 /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

I have this chunk of code in my `settings.py`:

```
import os
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['HERE.IS.MY.IP', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
print "ALLOWED_HOSTS: {}".format(ALLOWED_HOSTS)
```

In my mysql database I have this site table:

```
mysql> select * from django_site;
+----+--------------------+----------------+
| id | domain             | name           |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
|  1 | example.com        | example.com    |
|  5 | HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000 | projectsdb     |
|  8 | 127.0.0.1:8000     | projectsdb     |
|  9 | localhost:8000     | projectsdb     |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
```

I run the server locally on `127.0.0.1`:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 8000
ALLOWED_HOSTS: ['HERE.IS.MY.IP', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

Performing system checks...
# ...
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

If I go to this address `http://HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000` it works. But of course I'd like to open it using a local IP such as `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. But this does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: This should just work. What happens?

Comment: could you please try like this: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: I used `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] ` in my `settings.py`, now neither `http://HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000`, nor `http://localhost:8000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000` work.

Comment: Is your `/etc/hosts` completely default or have you edited it? What error message do you get when you visit localhost:8000 ?

Comment: @PeteTinkler I never edited my `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I found my newbie's mistake. More details here below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I solved it, silly me. I thought I was trying to access the server's page locally, but I wasn't. The server is running on a specific machine, and I was trying to access it locally from another machine (my laptop).

Explanations:
The server runs on `HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000`, only locally because I only gave the port 8000:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 8000
```

I am trying to access the server from the web browser on my laptop, so the IP used is different than `HERE.IS.MY.IP`.
If I want to access the page on `http://HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000` from my laptop I have no other choice than to allow the server access to external machines by running the server like this:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

or

```
$ python manage.py runserver HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000
```

and then to access it on my laptop's browser with the full IP (unless I map it on `/etc/hosts`) on `http://HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000`

Now if I want to access the page locally `only` from the server side, I have to run

```
$ python manage.py runserver 8000
```

, open a browser from the said server and then I can contact the pages `http://HERE.IS.MY.IP:8000`, `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and `http://localhost:8000` successfully.

So my mistake here was that I was accessing the server's page not from the server's browser itself but from another machine's.

Comment: I get this error when I run: python manage.py runserver avm:8000
\n
       "Error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"